# XSLT List Numbering

Tags: xslt

Having an issue with list numbering I'm wrestling with. Sometimes the list has a specific start number, sometimes it doesn't. Here's some xml

```
<document>
    <OrderedList Style="LowerAlpha">
    <Li><Para>Level 1, item 1</Para></Li>
      <Li><Para>Level 1, item 2</Para>
         <OrderedList Style="LowerRoman" StartAt="3">
            <Li><Para>Level 2, item 1</Para></Li>
            <Li><Para>Level 2, item 2</Para></Li>
         </OrderedList>
      </Li>
   </OrderedList>
</document>
```

I would like my output to be

a. List 1
b. List 1
iii. List 2
iv. List 2

I'm able to number perfectly when I have a don't have a start number using the following xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
       <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
       <xsl:template match="/">
          <root>
             <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </root>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="OrderedList">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="Li">
          <Para>
             <xsl:variable name="liCount" select="count(preceding-sibling::Li)+1"/>
             <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../@Style='LowerAlpha'">
                   <xsl:number format="a." value="$liCount"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../@Style='UpperAlpha'">
                   <xsl:number format="A." value="$liCount"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../@Style='LowerRoman'">
                   <xsl:number format="i." value="$liCount"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../@Style='UpperRoman'">
                   <xsl:number format="I." value="$liCount"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                   <xsl:number format="1." value="$liCount"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
             <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </Para>
       </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've tried adding the attribute value for StartAt in my numbering, and this works when StartAt is actually defined, but my output becomes NaN when StartAt is not defined.
`<xsl:variable name="liCount" select="count(preceding-sibling::Li)+number(../@StartAt)"/>`

I need to make my variable select statement conditional on whether there is a StartAt attribute or not, not sure if this is possible.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deal with it this way.

```
<xsl:variable name="liCount">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number(../@StartAt)">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::Li) + number(../@StartAt)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::Li)"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

I come across this issue often enough that I've written a function called "force-number()" and added it to my XSLT utility include.  If you have EXSLT function support, you may want to consider this option.